# Obtaining the list of all transformations in GAP

Tags: gap

Is there a command in GAP to obtain all transformations on $n$ symbols (so there should be $n^n$ of them). I can not find such a command in https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap53.html#X7B51CE257B814B09 but I would think that there is such a command since one can even find all finite groups of a given (low) order using GAP.
The output should be a list containing all transformation from [1..n] to [1..n].
So for example for n=2, the list looks like this:

[Transformation([1,2]),Transformation([1,1]),Transformation([2,2]),Transformation([2,1])];

Comment: Not sure if this is the most efficient way, but `OnTuples( tup, g);` can be used, where `tup := [1..n];` and g loops over all elements in `SymmetricGroup(n)`.

Comment: It also depends on the format of "all transformation" that you like, Please specify.

Comment: @FelixHuber I added an example for n=2. Im not sure whether I understand your comment correctly. Can you turn your comment in an answer even if it is not the most efficient way?

Comment: My bad. Please ignore my comment, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not "my" solution, from another GAP user:

`gap> List(FullTransformationSemigroup(3));`

does the job, returning

`[ Transformation( [ 1, 1, 1 ] ), Transformation( [ 1, 1, 2 ] ), 
   Transformation( [ 1, 1 ] ),   Transformation( [ 1, 2, 1 ] ), ...`

Comment: `Iterator` and `Enumerator` work for `FullTransformationSemigroup`, so instead of forming a list, you can also write constructions like `for s in FullTransformationSemigroup(n) do ...; od;` - see more in the GAP manual: https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap30.html#X7EF8910F82B45EC7 for enumerators and https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap30.html#X85A3F00985453F95 for iterators.